# Can't select object by clicking on its fill (not stroke) in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was working on something in Adobe Illustrator and accidentally pressed a button (*I don't know which key*), and now I can't select an object with its fill. I can only select by clicking on stroke.

What did I do, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Illustrator prefs
go to Selection and anchor
Uncheck "Object selection by path only"

That should do the trick!